# Можно ли использовать break в конструкции if?

Tags: php

```
if($post['t11']<0)
{
    $form->addError("error","You can't send negative units.");
    break;
}
```

Можно ли использовать break в конструкции if?

Comment: А какой смысл от данного действия? Что вы сделать-то хотели?  
Если if внутри цикла, тогда понятно. Можно так делать.

Comment: if находится не внутри цикла... Что можно использовать вместо break? exit()?

Comment: @eprivalov1, пока вы не ответите на вопрос "что вы пытаетесь достичь", мы не сможем ответить. Выход из if случается естественным путем, exit|die убьют скрипт целиком.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[break](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.break.php) прерывает выполнение текущей структуры `for`, `foreach`, `while`, `do-while` или `switch`.

Comment: @meboban,   поэтому, естественно  (из общих соображений) можно написать:

    if (expr)
      do {
         ...
         break;
         ...
      } while (0);
    
и утвердительно ответить на неожиданный вопрос ТС.

Answer (score 4):

Сам по себе break подразумевает невыполнение дальнейшей части кода, поэтому следующее за ним либо не выполнится, либо break будет срабатывать по условию if -- а значит, все последующее за ним с тем же успехом можно обернуть в else {} или if(!первоначальное условие), поэтому break не несет особого смысла. Если вы ищете примерно такой хак:

```
if (!validateNumber($var))
    break;
if (!validateText($text))
    break;
// реальная обработка данных
```

то задумка имеет право на жизнь, но PHP так не работает. Есть два альтернативных варианта:

1. Если необходимо просто выйти из текущего блока кода, то он оборачивается в функцию/метод (а он уже у вас обернут, если с архитектурой все в порядке), и в нужном месте ставится return. Все, что идет после сработавшего return, будет проигнорировано. return; является вполне валидной конструкцией, если метод в этом случае не должен ничего возвращать (хотя return null даст абсолютно аналогичный результат). Это позволяет делать удобное валидирование (пример будет ниже, тобы не порвать список).
2. Если внезапно выявилась ошибка, то можно прервать не только текущий блок кода, но и предшествующие блоки, выбросив исключение. Это позволяет строить большие модули, которые в случае ошибки не обрабатывают по цепочке возвращаемые значения от низкоуровненвых функций, а ловить исключения на верхнем. По аналогии с return, все, следующее за выброшенным исключением, будет проигнорировано.

Пример с валидацией:

```
public function validate() {
    if(!is_int($this->number)) {
        return false; // сразу говорим, что валидация провалилась, заодно экономим чуть-чуть процессорного времени, забивая на остальную часть кода.
    }
    if (isset($this->description) && !is_string($this->desctiption) {
        return false;
    }
    return true; // если все сработало успешно, то дополнительного условия для возврата true не требуется - мы счастливы уже тем, что выполнение кода дошло до этого пункта.
}
```

Чаще всего, правда, надо собрать все данные о неверных значениях и только потом возвращать их.

Answer (score 2):

Для вашего случая (если конечно этот break не внутри цикла и вы хотите его прервать) скорее всего уместнее использовать return, если вы хотите завершить текущую ф-ю или exit, если хотите остановить выполнение всего скрипта

Comment: Все-таки уместнее видимо будет использовать return false;

Comment: Ну false или другое значение - это уже зависит от того, что вы хотите получить от именно этой ф-и